# NativeScript: How can I catch tap event in case if user taps on empty space in RadListView?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, radlistview

[image]

If I tap on radlistview items - it catches events, but if I tap on empty space at the bottom of radlistview - then silence.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose of having tap event on empty area?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set (tap) and (itemTap) for RadListView.

```
<RadListView [items]="countries" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)" (tap)="tapOutSide($event)">
```

and in your .ts file

```
public onItemTap(args) {
        console.log("Item Tapped at cell index: " + args.index);
    }

    public tapOutSide($event) {
        console.log("TAPPED EMPTY SPACE");
        console.log($event.object);
    }
```

**P.S.** From the Screenshot, it looks like an Android phone and above solution works fine on Android. For ios, there is an open [issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6376) with nativescript.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But tap event doesn't emit in this case on Android for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: In that case try to wrap Listview inside a StackLayout and add (tap) event to StackLayout? And yes it was working for me.